# scala macro - how to expand an Array[TermName] to HList concatenation

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Suppose I have a case class

```
case class(id: Option[Long], name: String, gender: String)
```

Then I got the field names via compile-time reflect

```
val names = ... // Array(TermName(id), TermName(name), TermName("gender"))
```

How could I transform those names to `id :: name :: gender :: HNil` (which has type `Option[Long] :: String :: String :: HNil]`)

That is say I am looking for things like `q"..$name"` in quasiquote but expand names with `::` instead of `,`

Comment: Is this Shapeless's `HList`? Do you just want the names as strings? Do you have to use a macro? If it is Shapeless and you're not set on using a macro, reading the names off the `LabelledGeneric` instance is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @TravisBrown I have to use a macro, because I want to auto mapping an case class(with more than 22 fields) to slick table, and slick has its HList, I am using that one

Comment: You can convert a case class instance to an `HList` with e.g. `Generic[Foo].to(Foo(Some(1), "foo mcbar", "magical"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems could be done like this

```
   def hlistConcat[T: Liftable ](elems: Iterable[T]) = {
      val HNil = q"HNil": Tree
      elems.toList.reverse.foldLeft(HNil) { (list, c) =>
        q"$c :: $list"
      }
    }
```